# communication between mobile and web site

Tags: windows-mobile, jakarta-ee, mobile, java-me, mobile-website

Am not mobile developer or j2ee developer ,

I want some open source , which satisfy my below needs ,

1. send alert message to mobile ,(2-way communication) ,
2. Looking free open source ,
3. Need to store all message(incoming and outgoing messsages) into Database ,
4. We are not ready to spend money , may be one initial setup cost ready to spend,
5. We are not ready to install software in mobile , But if it is mandatory then ready to

install client  software into mobile,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without installing software on mobile, your best bet will be SMS.

You can get setup very cheaply to send SMS using a gateway provider such as http://www.clickatell.com/.  (There are many providers out there). The cost of sending a SMS is generally a few $cents, the cost varies on the destination country & mobile operator.

Sending SMS is straightforward, however being able to receive a message requires a bit more setup, but its still relatively simple. Have a look at http://www.clickatell.com/products/two_way.php to see the steps & costs involved.

Clickatell will provide good stats on all messages sent.

Comment: ok am ready to install software in mobile...guide me...in j2me

Comment: I can't help you there - I don't know of any j2me software for this. Bear in mind that while SMS is universal, j2me is not and it will limit your application only to devices that support j2me